# Übersetzung von "From what I've heard, ..."

Tags: translation, english-to-german

> From what I've heard, the city is not safe after sunset.

Wie übersetzt man das am besten? Wäre es so?

> Von dem ich gehört habe, ist die Stadt nach Sonnenuntergang nicht sicher.

Ich habe an zwei Stellen Zweifel: Ist "von **dem**" richtig, und braucht man hier ein Komma?

Comment: Angeblich ist die Stadt nach Sonnenuntergang nicht sicher.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nein, "von dem ich gehört habe" ist nicht richtig. Das wäre die Übersetzung für "that I've heard of".

Die Konstruktion, die Deinem Vorschlag am nächsten kommt, ist

> Von dem, **was** ich gehört habe, ist ...

Allerdings passt "von" **hier** nicht so richtig. Es drückt eher nicht die Schlussfolgerung aus ("ich habe etwas gehört, und deshalb glaube ich, dass..."), sondern eine Auswahl ("ich habe dies und das gehört, und dabei auch...").

Beispiel:

> Von dem, was ich über German SE gehört habe, hat mir besonders gefallen, dass man hier so schnell eine Antwort bekommt.

In Deinem Fall würde ich stattdessen "nach" bevorzugen, also:

> Nach dem, was ich gehört habe, ist die Stadt nach Sonnenuntergang nicht sicher.

Die Variante mit "von dem, was ..." wirst Du aber sicher auch hören. Beides ist eher umgangssprachlich, und nicht jeder nimmt es immer so genau.

Schriftlich würde ich bevorzugen:

> Ich habe gehört, dass die Stadt nach Sonnenuntergang nicht sicher sei.

Answer (score 7):

Ich würde sagen:

> Wie ich gehört habe, ist die Stadt nach Sonnenuntergang nicht sicher.

Ein Komma brauchst du, da es sich hierbei um einen Nebensatz ("Wie ich gehört habe") und einen Hauptsatz ("ist die Stadt nach Sonnenuntergang nicht sicher") handelt.

Answer (score 6):

Noch eine (etwas freiere) Variante:

> Man sagt, nach Sonnenuntergang sei die Stadt kein sicherer Ort.

Ich würde also auch den Part "the city is not safe" nicht ganz wörtlich übersetzen, weil „die Stadt ist nicht sicher“ für sich genommen mehrdeutig ist: droht der Stadt insgesamt Unheil, etwa ein Angriff / Überfall? Oder sind die Leute selbst innerhalb der Stadtmauern nicht vor Überfällen etc. sicher? Das kann sich nur aus dem Kontext ergeben - und die zweite Variante liegt für meinen Geschmack näher.

Comment: Das wäre dann eine interpretierende Übersetzung - oder ist "the city is not safe" weniger mehrdeutig?

Comment: Nein, m.E. ebenso. Interpretierend auf jeden Fall, das ist richtig.

Comment: PS: Habe die negative Formulierung übernommen - die Abweichung von der Originalformulierung verwirrt sonst...

Answer (score 4):

Die meiner Meinung idiomatisch natürlichste Übersetzung ist

> Soweit ich weiß, ...

Dies ist eine häufig verwendete Phrase, die auch sinngemäß dem englischen Original sehr nahe kommt. (Denn ich weiß hauptsächlich Dinge, die ich irgendwo gehört oder gelesen habe.)

Comment: Ich könnte es aber auch aus eigenem Erleben wissen (und dann die Einschränkung, weil ich nicht sicher bin, ob es noch aktuell ist).

Comment: @chirlu: Ja, stimmt.

Answer (score 0):

> Vom Hörensagen weiss ich, dass die Stadt nach Sonnenuntergang nicht sicher sein soll.`

Das geht aber schon in Richtung Klatsch und Tratsch.

> Wie ich gehört habe, ist die Stadt ... `

oder

> Nach dem zu urteilen, was ich gehört habe, ist die Stadt...`

Hier ist der Sinn durch das Urteilen minimal verändert, aber es klingt besser und diese Varianten suggerieren eher seriöse Quellen für das Gehörte.